# How do I remove partially installed files from the Linux directory on my chromebook without having to reinstall Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, chromebook, pip

I am currently trying to learn how to analyse social media data and the online course I was taking advised us to install spyder. I first tried to install the ubuntu package and used the command `sudo apt-get install spyder` only to realise I may have installed an outdated version. So then I attempted to uninstall this version and install the pip3 version of spyder, which I thought would likely be better for me anyway (since I'm using tweepy) but then I received an error message.

As it turns out, the ubuntu version of spyder was still taking up storage somehow despite the fact that i thought I uninstalled it. I am still able to run this version of spyder, but the problem is I think the pip3 version of spyder may be partially installed because now there is less than 100 kb available in the linux directory on my chromebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Synaptic Package Manager (SPM)](https://itsfoss.com/synaptic-package-manager/) to help uninstall packages. However, if SPM fails to run because the installation or removal is in an indeterminate state, i.e. due to broken packages, follow the directions in the SPM warning message, e.g. open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) and enter:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

[Make Tech Easier](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-broken-packages-ubuntu/) and [Foss Linux](https://www.fosslinux.com/8782/fix-broken-linux-mint-updates-due-to-the-broken-packages.htm) have more detailed description of fixing or removing broken packages.